# Is Actions for Families mandatory for Actions targeting children?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have an Action that requires email address or Account Linking and is primarily made for children.
But Actions for Families disallows use of Account Linking.

Can I publish an Action designed for kids but not a part of Actions for Families?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, StackOverflow is not a suitable place for legal advice, and if in doubt you should consult your own lawyer.

However, the answer is probably **"no"**. If your action is "designed for kids", you **must** make it part of the Actions for Family program.

As per the [Actions on Google policies](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies#actions_for_families):

> If your Action targets children or provides content explicitly for children, it must participate in the Actions for Families program. This includes both Actions targeting children as their primary audience or as one of their audiences.